# Adding numbers in plot

Tags: r, date, plot, comparison, line

Hi everyone Im having problems with a plot and i cant find a script that can do this ...

I already looked for an answer here but couldnt found it, at least with the keywords i tried.

Anyways the plot i need to make is a plot that continuosly adds the number before.

I made a picture so its easier to explain myself.

[image]

Hope it makes sense

This is the data I need to plot:

```
Data$TMM
[1] 720 540 400 540 360 720 360
> Data$Date
[1] "2015-09-24" "2015-09-26" "2015-10-01" "2015-10-03" "2015-10-09" "2015-10-10"
[7] "2015-10-11"
```

TMM as in Total Money Made. The plot should go increasing and the idea is to make one of this plots for each month and then overlap it with different months with different line colors and compare between them.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Not clear yet! Add some code what you have tried!

Comment: Oh dont tell me that!! haha mm for example with the Data i gave above it would be the 24 of september = 720, the 26 of september would be 540 PLUS the previous 720 and so on.

Comment: So the 24 septmeber would show 720 and the 26 of september would display 1260 (720 + 540 of that day)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very simple!

```
plot(as.Date(Data$Date),cumsum(Data$TMM),type="b",col=3,ylim=c(0.95,1.15)*range(cumsum(Data$TMM)))
```

For numbers experiment with text

```
text(as.Date(Data$Date)[1],cumsum(Data$TMM)[1], (Data$TMM)[1],pos = 4,cex=.6)
for (i in 2:length(Data$TMM))
text(as.Date(Data$Date)[i],cumsum(Data$TMM)[i], paste(cumsum(Data$TMM)[i-1],"\n",
                                                      (Data$TMM)[i],sep=""),pos = 3,cex=.6)
```

Answer (score 0):

Update: I missed that you were looking for a cumulative sum. If you look at `?cumsum` in R you will see the various cumulative functions that will help you moving forward. If you want to make it easy to work with and retain, especially in a clean `ggplot()` layered approach, I still would recommend adding a column to your df. So...

Why don't you add a new column that adds the previous values and simply plot that series? So, assuming that your new values to plot will be in `new_column`

```
add_previous_values <- function(df){
    df$new_column <- cumsum(df$TMM)
}

add_previous_values(df)
```